# how to do a for loop on fixtures in cypress - array with variable

Tags: for-loop, variables, cypress

**the fixtures:**

```
{
  "new_application" : 1,
  "diagnosis_application" : 2,
  "details_completion_application" : 3,
  "awaiting_treatment_application" : 5,
  "closed_application" : 6,
  "canceled_application" : 7

}
```

I need the variables names

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.keys()` to get all the keys from the JSON object.

```js
var jsonObj = {
  "new_application" : 1,
  "diagnosis_application" : 2,
  "details_completion_application" : 3,
  "awaiting_treatment_application" : 5,
  "closed_application" : 6,
  "canceled_application" : 7

}
Object.keys(jsonObj)
```

`Object.keys(jsonObj)` will return an array with all the keys:

```js
[
  'new_application',
  'diagnosis_application',
  'details_completion_application',
  'awaiting_treatment_application',
  'closed_application',
  'canceled_application',
]
```

To get the keys one by one you can use the for-Each loop like this:

```js
Object.keys(jsonObj).forEach(function(key) {
    var value = jsonObj[key]; //Gets each key one by one
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is `for...in`, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```js
const object = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

for (const property in object) {
  console.log(`${property}: ${object[property]}`);
}

// expected output:
// "a: 1"
// "b: 2"
// "c: 3"
```